# WCF .net Invoking Webservices methods dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

Let's say I have 2 webservices hosting locally - both of them having the same functionality.
In the same solution I have a console application to test these web services.

```
//SERVICE 1
namespace Service1
{

[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceAuthentication
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Authenticate(Authentication aut);
}


[DataContract]
public class Authentication
{
    [DataMember]
    public string username;
    [DataMember]
    public string password;
}

public class AuthenticationService : IServiceAuthentication
{
    public string Authenticate(Authentication aut)
    {
        if (aut.username == "Test1" && aut.password == "Test1")
        {
            return "passed";
        }
        else
        {
            return "failed";
        }
    }
}
}
```

**BOTH OF THEM THE SAME FUNCTIONALITY - JUST DIFFERENT CREDENTIALS**

```
//SERVICE 2
namespace Service1
{

[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceAuthentication
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Authenticate(Authentication aut);
}


[DataContract]
public class Authentication
{
    [DataMember]
    public string username;
    [DataMember]
    public string password;
}

public class AuthenticationService : IServiceAuthentication
{
    public string Authenticate(Authentication aut)
    {
        if (aut.username == "Test2" && aut.password == "Test2")
        {
            return "passed";
        }
        else
        {
            return "failed";
        }
    }
}
}
```

**CONSOLE APP TO TESTS BOTH WEBSERVIES**

```
namespace WebserviceTest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WSHttpBinding wsHttpBinding = new WSHttpBinding();
        EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8080/Service1/Authentication");
        IServiceAuthentication authService1 = new ChannelFactory<IServiceAuthentication>(wsHttpBinding, endpointAddress).CreateChannel();
        Console.Write(authService1.Authenticate(new Authentication() { username = "test1", password = "test1" }));
        Console.ReadKey();

        EndpointAddress endpointAddress2 = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8081/Service2/Authentication");
        IServiceAuthentication authService2 = new ChannelFactory<IServiceAuthentication>(wsHttpBinding, endpointAddress2).CreateChannel();
        Console.Write(authService2.Authenticate(new Authentication() { username = "test2", password = "test2" }));
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceAuthentication
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Authenticate(Authentication aut);
}


[DataContract]
public class Authentication
{
    [DataMember]
    public string username;
    [DataMember]
    public string password;
}

}
```

The problem that I am encountering is that the methods are being executed from the web service side properly but the object parameter Authentication is null - although I am passing "test1",test1" and "test2","test2". For both calls the obviuosly the services are returning failed.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you just copied contracts into three projects and you now expect that these contracts are same?

Comment: Yes - I am new to web services - what is the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make it work this way. Define contracts in separate assembly and reference it from all three projects.

If you create contracts in each assembly again it will use some default naming. The default naming uses some convention to define namespaces for serialized data and it is among others based on .NET namespace of the contract. So once the contract is serialized it will look like transferring the same data but the service will skip it because from its perspective the data will be defined in wrong namespace.

Edit:

If you want to have data contracts in copied to multiple assemblies you must define their namespace manually `[DataContract(Namespace = "SomeUri")]` and use the same value over all definitions.

Comment: Ok I sepereated the contracts in different assembly. I added a reference in the console test app - so far so good. Now how can I add the same reference in the web services projects?

Comment: Add reference from context menu on services projects.